# How do I remove the whitespace at the bottom from my Bootstrap page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a little problem regarding my Bootstrap page. At the bottom of my page, there is a unwanted 5px long space. I've tried everything, like setting the margin and padding both to 0, but nothing happened. Does someone know a working solution to remove it?

Edit: Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="width: 100%">
    <video style="width: 100%" id="player-video">
        <source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are only having a video element into your page ? Just based on this code, I dont really see any problem

Comment: @MaxiGui Yeah, but there is this white space at the bottom of the page

Comment: Very good but show it to us by print screen, css, html, just based on this it is hard to tell

Comment: Also, did you check in multiple browsers to see if the unwanted space was there and might as well add the browsers you did check this.  Last thing you can go to this page to check your page  https://www.codeply.com/p

Comment: What if you press F-12 in your browser and use the selection tool to highlight the area of the page where the space is. Then look at styles to find out what is causing it. Then you might be able to add your own CSS with more specificity to override the current layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please give your video tag a `display:flex` and `height: 100%` that will help to fill any white space that has not been allocated.
on my demo, it worked out just fine.

If that doesn't work please let me know.

Note that I had bootstrap in the demo folder.

```
 <video style="width: 100%; display: flex; height: 100%;" id="player-video">
        <source src="3. create-react-app.mp4" autoplay type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```